# How to convert string True / False Pandas columns to int based on column index?

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, integer

I have a very large dataframe where only the first two columns are not bools.  However everything is brought in as a string due to the source.  The True/False fields do contain actual blanks (not nan) as well and are spelled out 'True' and 'False'

I'm trying to come up with a dynamic-ish way to do this without typing out or listing every column.

```
  ndf.iloc[:,2:].astype(bool)
```

That seems to at least run and change it to bool, but when I add 'inplace=True' it has no effect at storing the property types. I've also tried the code below to no luck.  It runs but doesn't actually do anything that I can tell.

```
  ndf.iloc[:,2:] = ndf.iloc[:,2:].astype(bool)
```

I need to be able to write this table back into a database as 0s and 1s ultimately.  I'm not the most versed at bools and am hoping there is an easy one liner way to do this that I don't know yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually

```
ndf.iloc[:,2:] = ndf.iloc[:,2:].astype(bool)
```

should work and change your data from `str/object` to `bool`. It's just you get the same print out with `'True'` and `True`. Check with `ndf.dtypes` to see the changes after that command.

If you want the booleans as `0` and `1`, try:

```
ndf.iloc[:,2:] = ndf.iloc[:,2:].astype(bool).astype(int)
```

Comment: That is essentially what I had in my 2nd attempt that didn't appear to work with looking at dtypes, but it does appear that it worked and I missed it.  Thanks I will accept this answer when it lets me.